# Best way to shrink the table into one column

Tags: tables

I have a table which I want to shrink in one column of a two column scientific paper. What is the best possible way to do this; keeping a good look of the table and overall paper? Below is the MWE of my table code.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newcounter{mytempeqncnt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[long,c2]{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[b!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\centering
\caption{Simulation Results for the Test Networks}
\label{Table3}
\begin{tabular}[t!]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Eigenvalue Ratio $|\lambda_2|\backslash|\lambda_1|$}}\\ 
\hline
\textbf{Test System} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Slack Bus}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{\textbf{Power Losses} \\ \textbf{Minimization}}}  \\ 
\hline 
& $Y_{g1}$ &$Y_{g2}$&$Y_{g3}$&$Y_{g1}$&$Y_{g2}$&$Y_{g3}$\\
\hline 
4-bus &&&&&&\\
\hline
IT 37-bus&0.0185&5.3$\times 10^{-6}$&2.7$\times 10^{-5}$&3.1$\times 10^{-6}$&1.2$\times 10^{-5}$&2.3$\times 10^{-4}$\\
\hline
IT 111-bus&&&&&&\\
\hline      
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To address this problem, it would be preferable if the dimensions of the two columns of scientific paper were included in your MWE.

Comment: 'Prepare your CR paper in full-sized format on standard 8½ × 11 in
(21.6  ×  27.9  cm)  bond  paper.    If  you  are  using  A4  (metric)  paper,
please cut the paper length to 28 cm.  In formatting your page, set top and bottom margins to
25 mm (1 in) and left and right margins to 18 mm (0.7 in).  (If you are
using A4 paper, set the right margin to 12 mm.)  The column width is
88 mm (3.45 in).  The space between the two columns is 5 mm (0.2 in).
Paragraph indentation is about 3.5 mm (0.14 in).' From paper Guidlines.

Comment: You can either use the `table*` environment, so it spreads over  both columns, or you swap rows and columns.

Comment: I do not want to spread the table over two columns. The other sol might work.  Let me try!!

Comment: Off-topic: Since you have the instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, you should delete the earlier instruction `\usepackage{color,colortbl}`. Also, the `subfigure` package is obsolete; use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use vertical lines. Yes, the widths of 7 vertical lines do add up. And, the vertical lines aren't needed. And, get rid of the whitespace padding at the edges of the table.
- Allow a line break in the header of the first column.
- Use a `tabular*` environment, set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`, set the width to `\columnwidth`, and let LaTeX figure out the amount of intercolumn whitespace.
- Optional (and not very pretty, but very effective): instead of `$5.3\times 10^{-6}$`, write `5.3E-6`, etc.
- A separate suggestion: Load the `booktabs` package and use `\toprule`, `\cmidrule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` for well-spaced horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{subfigure}  % obsolete
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newcounter{mytempeqncnt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[switch]{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[long,c2]{optidef}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\medmuskip-0mu

\caption{Simulation Results for the Test Networks}
\label{Table3}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    l *{6}{c} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Eigenvalue Ratio $|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1|$}}\\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7}
\thead{\textbf{Test} \\ \textbf{System}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Slack Bus}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{\textbf{Power Losses} \\ \textbf{Minimization}}}  \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& $Y_{\!g1}$ & $Y_{\!g2}$ & $Y_{\!g3}$ & $Y_{\!g1}$ & $Y_{\!g2}$ & $Y_{\!g3}$ \\
\midrule 
4-bus \\

IT 37-bus 
& 0.0185 & $5.3\times 10^{-6}$ 
& $2.7\times 10^{-5}$ & $3.1\times 10^{-6}$ 
& $1.2\times 10^{-5}$ & $2.3\times 10^{-4}$\\
IT 111-bus \\
\midrule 
IT 37-bus& 0.0185 & 5.3E-6 & 2.7E-5 & 3.1E-6 & 1.2E-5 & 2.3E-4\\
\bottomrule    
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```